# Using __call__ and @property to have a class return a value like a normal variable when called

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a class that can contain a variable and a unit (e.g. 5 m/s) but I want it to behave like a normal variable whenever it is called. My intention was to use the `@property` decorator in addition to the `__call__` magic method to achieve this.

My code looks like this:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import typing as tp
import numpy as np


@dataclass
class _Value():
    value: float

    @property
    def __call__(self):
        return self.value


@dataclass
class _Unit():
    unit: str

    @property
    def __call__(self):
        return self.unit


@dataclass
class DataUnit():
    value: tp.Any
    unit: tp.Any

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.value = _Value(self.value)
        self.unit = _Unit(self.unit)

    @property
    def __call__(self):
        return self.value


variable = DataUnit(value=1, unit='kg')

print(variable)
```

When I run the code, I want to receive the value '1' from the print function, however I instead receive `DataUnit(value=_Value(value=1), unit=_Unit(unit='kg'))`. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Could this have something to do with me using the `@dataclass` decorator?

I'm using Python 3.11 by the way.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are doing some wrong things

you should not use `property` decorator with `magic_methods`.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import typing as tp
import numpy as np


@dataclass
class _Value():
    value: float

    @property
    def __call__(self):
        return self.value


@dataclass
class _Unit():
    unit: str

    @property
    def __call__(self):
        return self.unit


@dataclass
class DataUnit():
    value: tp.Any
    unit: tp.Any

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.value = _Value(self.value)
        self.unit = _Unit(self.unit)

    @property
    def __call__(self):
        return self.value


variable = DataUnit(value=1, unit='kg')

print(variable.__call__) # This will work because you have set the property decorator on `__call__` method so it will treat `__call__` as a property now onwards. Also you lose the magic of `__call__` due to this.
```

Now to build what you want you should override `__str__` method

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import typing as tp
import numpy as np


@dataclass
class _Value():
    value: float

    def __call__(self, *args: tp.Any, **kwds: tp.Any) -> tp.Any:
        return self.value


@dataclass
class _Unit():
    unit: str

    def __call__(self, *args: tp.Any, **kwds: tp.Any) -> tp.Any:
        return self.unit


@dataclass
class DataUnit():
    value: tp.Any
    unit: tp.Any

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.value = _Value(self.value)
        self.unit = _Unit(self.unit)

    def __str__(self) :
        return f"{self.value}"


variable = DataUnit(value=1, unit='kg')

print(variable)
```